# C# object initialization

Tags: c#

Having program with such code :

```
var subtree = new Tree<int>(5, EnumeratorOrder.BreadthFirstSearch) { 1, 2 };

var tree = new Tree<int>(7, EnumeratorOrder.BreadthFirstSearch) { subtree, 10, 15 };
```

I сan't understan what means `{ 1, 2 }`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I сan't understan what means { 1, 2 }

The `{1, 2}` are [Collection Initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

They represent a short-hand version of

```
var temp = new Tree<int>(5, EnumeratorOrder.BreadthFirstSearch);
temp.Add(1);
temp.Add(2);

var subtree = temp;
```

Note regarding initial assignment to `temp`: *The meaning of assignment is evaluate the left, evaluate the right, do the assignment. Evaluating the right produces side effects, and those effects must be ordered before the effect of the assignment.* See comments for a full discussion.

Comment: Though this gets the idea across, I note that `subtree` is not assigned until *after* the `Add` calls. This is actually a shorthand for `var temp = new ... ; temp.Add(1); temp.Add(2); var subtree = temp;`

Comment: @EricLippert: Thank you for chiming in on this.  Updated my answer accordingly.  Why is a temporary variable used?  My naive assumption is that the compiler could enforce the order "Allocate and assign subtree, call subtree.Add(1), call subtree.Add(2)".

Comment: A collection initializer simply produces a value; the fact that you personally like to use that value as the initial value of a local variable declaration is a fact about you, not about the collection initializer. That value could be an operand, an argument, or simply discarded; it need not be assigned to anything.

Comment: Second, suppose one of the `Add`s throws, and the assignment is to a field. **Do you expect the assignment to have succeeded and visible to code that can see the field even if one of the adds throws?** Why should that field be assigned to the collection *without* a successful Add? That seems very bizarre and error prone.

Comment: Third, what should this do?  `Y y = new Y() { M(y) };` where the variable is a local. Under your proposal this should work, and should pass the `new Y()` to `M` before calling `Add`. That seems bad. If the expression produces a temporary value then `y` is not assigned at the moment of the call to `Add` and therefore this code is a compile-time error, as it should be.

Comment: Fourth, same situation, but this time it is a field. Under your interpretation again, this should pass the `new Y()` as the argument to `M`. Under my interpretation this should pass `null`. Which seems more sensible to you?

Comment: Fifth, suppose that the assignment is to a property: `P = new Y() { z };`. Is your proposal that first the constructor is called, then the setter of P is called, then the getter of P is called, and then the Add method is called?  Why should the getter of P be called at all here?  What if P doesn't even have a getter? write-only properties are weird, but they are legal.

Comment: Sixth, now consider all the cases above where the assignment is to an element of an array, or to an indexer; all those cases have similar bad behaviour under your proposal. I could continue coming up with even more odd cases, but I think I will leave it at those for now.

Comment: I knew my view was naive, but not in what way.  Thank you for explaining.  When you say `A collection initializer simply produces a value; the fact ... is a fact about you, not about the collection initializer.` is "value" is the fully initialized `new Tree<int>(5, EnumeratorOrder.BreadthFirstSearch) { 1, 2 }`?

Comment: Right. Another way of looking at it is: the meaning of assignment is *evaluate the left, evaluate the right, do the assignment*.  Evaluating the right produces side effects, and those effects must be ordered before the effect of the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [collection initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

> Collection initializers let you specify one or more element initializers when you initialize a collection class that implements IEnumerable or a class with an Add extension method. The element initializers can be a simple value, an expression or an object initializer. By using a collection initializer you do not have to specify multiple calls to the Add method of the class in your source code; the compiler adds the calls.

Comment: Closest answer, and points the OP to what the class Tree should do/have in order to enable this.